# How to trace SQL Server stored proceduce

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-4, sql-server-profiler

I want to use SQL Server Profiler to trace parameters of stored procedure that was run by Entity Framework. Which event I should check in Events selection?

NOTE: I want to see execute statement, include parameter value

Answer (score 0):

Try the SP:Starting and SP:Completed events. Note that these events only appear when the "Show All Events" checkbox is checked when creating or modifying your trace.

Comment: I have selected SP:Starting and SP:Completed events. But it just show Parameter name ONLY (EX: proc_myStoredProcedure @p0). I want to see value of parameter was passed to SP. Thanks your answer